# path to subfolders is confusing

Tags: php

My folder structure

root->
          my_framework-> inc / header.php
                                              -> register / index.php

In the index.php which resides in register folder, how do I include header.php which is inside inc folder?

This seems to be very tricky.

I tried:

1) `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/my_framework/inc/header.php'` = shows error saying no file found in that path

2) `../inc/header.php` = no error but css not applicable. WHen view on source, path reads myframework/register/inc/header.php

3) `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].dir(_FILE_).'/inc/header.php'` = path error

What is the correct way to include header which is inside inc folder in any subfolder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
include('../inc/header.php');
```

The css is not working probably because you are using relative paths. Change the paths of the css and js files to `/path/to/css-file.css`

Comment: thanks I chaned path for css relative to register folder and it works. But how to change the path (for css) if I were to call from another folder inside register or even outside register folder?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you use the css.. if you set it with an absolute path it will be included every time.. When I say absolute path I mean you must use a `/` before the public path of the css..

Comment: I got it now..Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
1) $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/my_framework/inc/header.php' = shows error saying no file found in that path

2) ../inc/header.php = no error but css not applicable. WHen view on source, path reads myframework/register/inc/header.php

3) $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].dir(_FILE_).'/inc/header.php' = path error
```

1.
This looks like it should work but relies on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.  Which you might not have if you were running from the command line.  Did you echo the constant?  Or the path?

2.
Relative path issues.

If in header you have css path as: `static/stylesheet.css`. On the index page in my_framework the path resolves to `/my-framework/static/stylesheet.css`.  On the register index page it would become `/my-framework/register/static/stylesheet.css`.
It's easier to base all your paths from your web root (initial slash).  `/my-framework/static/stylesheet.css`.

You can create a variable in your header called something like $base and prefix that to your web paths.  `$base = '/my_framework'` then later `href="<?php echo $base; ?>/static/stylesheet.css"`.  Bear in mind for links.  Needed if you move your site about during development and use sub-folders.

3.
It's `dirname(__FILE__)` not `dir(_FILE_)`.  Magic constants have double underscores.  You can switch out `dirname(__FILE__)` for `__DIR__`.   This is a file system path.  You may need to use this if your relative include paths don't appear to resolve.

Concatenating your document root with `__DIR__` also doesn't make sense, you'll end up with something like: `/var/www/var/www/foo/bar`.